# How to insert the number of posts from the category in wp _title?

Tags: wp-title

For example, the site has a category "News", in which there are 37 posts num.

How to insert into **wp_title** the number of records (37) in this category.

those, if we go to the "News" category, the title should be displayed:

```
<title>37 posts in News category | Site name</title>
```

Help me please,
Regards, Anna

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your theme supports WordPress adding the title tag using `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` (it should!) you can use the [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) filter to insert the post count in the right place without needing to parse the full title or modify existing elements that might have been customised, such as the separator:

```
function wpse_323260_document_title_category_count( $title ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $category = get_queried_object();

        $title['title'] = sprintf(
            '%d posts in %s Category',
            $category->count,
            esc_html( single_cat_title( '', false ) )
        );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'wpse_323260_document_title_category_count' );
```